# Как сделать условие, что если строка заканчивается на цифру, то после нее должна быть точка и 2 символа

Tags: javascript, регулярные-выражения

Есть regExp, которые матчит домены сайтов.

```
/^([\wёa-я-\d]{2,}\.)+([\wёa-я-\d]{2,})$/
```

Как мне определить, что если в конце стоит цифра, то после нее обязательно должна идти точка ну и 2 символа потом?

Допустим есть домен, он валидный

```
google.com
```

Но если в конце поставить любую цифру, то будет считаться, что это должен быть домен 3 уровня и ждать точку и после нее 2 символа

```
google.com5 - не валидный

google.com5.ru - валидный
```

Comment: Не совсем понятно, в конце чего. Наверное, стоит привести примеры.

Comment: @vsemozhebuty обновил

Comment: `/^([\wёa-я-]{2,}\.)+([ёa-я]{2,})$/` или ``/^([\wёa-я-]{2,}\.)+([a-zA-Zёa-я]{2,})$/``. `\w` сам по себе находит цифры, не нужно ещё и `\d` добавлять в символьный класс.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew да, вы правы. Тогда мне надо во второй части проверить оканчивается ли на цифру

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew исключать цифры тоже не вариант, в середине ставить можно

Comment: Ладно, `^(?!.*\d$)([\wёa-я-]{2,}\.)+([\wёa-я-]{2,})$` подойдёт. И `^([\wёa-я-]{2,}\.)+([\wёa-я-]+[a-zA-Z_ёa-я-])$` тоже.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew спасибо большое)!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Помните, что `\w` - это `[A-Za-z0-9_]`. Чтобы исключить цифры, используйте `[A-Za-z_]`. Так как в конце строки требуется два и более символов, `{2,}` можно заменить на `+` (один и более), если добавить шаблон с исключёнными цифрами.

```js
^(?:[\wёa-я-]{2,}\.)+[\wёa-я-]+[a-zA-Z_ёa-я-]$
```

См. [пример работы регулярного выражения](https://regex101.com/r/dAPRmz/2).

Другой вариант - использование негативного блока просмотра вперёд:

```js
^(?!.*\d$)(?:[\wёa-я-]{2,}\.)+[\wёa-я-]{2,}$
```

`(?!.*\d$)` означает, что последний символ не может быть цифрой.

Answer (score 1):

Ну в TLD по идее и не ожидается цифр (по крайней мере, среди ходовых TLD нет с цифрами, на момент написания этого ответа)... поэтому:

```
/^([\wёa-я-\d]+\.)+([a-zёa-я]{2,})$/i
```

---

А вот вариант с более адекватным для имен доменов рег.выражением - оно **не** матчит имена с `_` ([разве он допустим?](https://www.entrust.com/ru/blog/2019/01/removal-of-underscores-from-domain-names/#:%7E:text=Underscore%20characters%20are%20not%20permitted%20in%20domain%20names%20in%20accordance%20with%20RFC%201035)), а также с `-` в начале или в конце имени поддомена:

```js
const re = /^((?:[a-zёa-я\d]+-)*[a-zёa-я\d]+\.)+([a-zёa-я]{2,})$/i;

inp.addEventListener('input', () => void(rslt.textContent = re.test(inp.value)));
inp.dispatchEvent(new InputEvent('input'));
```

```html
<input id="inp" value="foo-bar123.baz42.io">
<span id="rslt"></span>
```

Попутно этим исправлен и квантификатор `{2,}` в части доменного имени - он некорректен, т.к. имена поддоменов (т.е., все части доменного имена кроме TLD) [вполне могут](https://1.fm/) состоять из одного символа.

Comment: да, Вы правы) - так же нельзя в конце поддомена)  у меня вышло вот так ^((?!-)[a-zёa-я-\d]+(?<!-)\.)+((?!-)[a-zёa-я-]{2,}(?<!-))$

Comment: @Andrew, да, и в начале `-` тоже нельзя (уточнил ответ). Крч, разумнее чекать дефис только между других символов набора, что и делает вторая регулярка.